# Коррекция\поиск ссылки в тексте PHP

Tags: php, ссылки

Пишу системку BB кодов для своего проекта. Решил упростить работу ссылками.
Прошу подсказать как автоматически исправлять не полные ссылки?
Допустим пользователь ввел  **ya.ru**  , а мне надо,чтобы оно исправилось на **http://ya.ru**

На обработку поступает введенная ссылка в тэгах [url='ссылка']Название сайта[/url]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрать регулярным выражением на части и проверить начало строки со ссылкой.

Что-то типа (не проверял):
<!--language: php-->

```
function getLink( $bbString) {
    $pattern = '#[url=([^]]+)]([^[]+)[/url]#';
    if( !preg_match( $pattern, $bbString, $matches)) return false;
    $link = $matches[1];
    if( substr( $link, 0, 4) != 'http') $link = 'http://' . $link;
    return $link;
}
```

Ссылки в помощь:

1. preg_match() http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
2. регулярные выражения: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Sergiks, спасибо за Ваш ответ. Он открыл мне глаза. 
Оказывается моя проблема была в том, что я не умел использовать регулярные выражения.  Пойду развиваться дальше ;)